# Swift 3 - CollectionView select not visible

Tags: swift, uitableview, exception, scroll, uicollectionview

every time i try to select a cell which is not visible, i get an exception:

```
let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! CustomCell
```

Thats why i decided to first scroll to it so it gets visibile and then to select it:

```
collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: [], animated: true)
let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! CustomCell
```

But i still get:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

for this line:

```
let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! CustomCell
```

Anybody could help me with this issue?

Thanks and Greetings!

Comment: Since `cellForItem` is defined to return nil for cells that aren't visible, I have to ask, why are you trying to select one at all?  (I suspect the scroll problem is that the UI isn't updated until the event loop runs, therefore the cell hasn't had a chance to become visible...but I'm not sure of that.)

Comment: Why would you want to select a cell that is not visible in the first place?

Comment: i am implementing a preselect, and the cell which has to be preselected is not visible... so?

Comment: Try to dequeue the cell method  rather than cell for method

Comment: what do mean exactly?

Answer (score 3):

We have did select method in UICollectionViewDelegate.

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
      //here you can access the cell 
      guard let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? 
      CustomCell else { return }
      //write your code here
}
```